# MySQL Foreign keys - Error 150 while creating tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have written some SQL code to create five tables with several relations(foreign keys).

The first foreign key relation works fine, the tables are created without any errors, but when I try to create `gasten_url_toegangscodes` I get the following error:

> `#1005 - Can't create table 'dbname.gasten_url_toegangscodes' (errno: 150).`

I've read the docs about foreign keys and I still can't find the problem.. The most strange thing about this is that it works in the first three tables..

Can anyone help me please?

My full SQL code is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groepen` (
  `id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gasten` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bedrijf` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uniek` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `groepid` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (groepid) REFERENCES `groepen` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `passen` (
  `id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `color` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '#FFFFFF',
  `bekend` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `welkom` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `aantal` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nummer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `begrens` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `naam` (`naam`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gasten_url_toegangscodes` (
  `uniek` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `unieke_url_code` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (uniek) REFERENCES `gasten` (`uniek`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gasten_tickets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pas_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `uniek` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `barcode` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `secret_key` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `download_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_download_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `scanned` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL,
  `scanned_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (uniek) REFERENCES `gasten` (`uniek`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (pas_id) REFERENCES `passen` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you create an index on `gasten.uniek`? `INDEX idx_uniek (uniek)`

Comment: The other difference is the default charset on `gasten_url_toegangscodes`

Comment: Thanks, this works! Been searching for hours! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I've put it in as an answer then. I wasn't sure the index would fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an index on `gasten.uniek`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gasten` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bedrijf` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uniek` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `groepid` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_uniek` (`uniek`),
  FOREIGN KEY (groepid) REFERENCES `groepen` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And set the charset of the FK in `gasten_url_toegangscodes` the same as that of the related column in `gasten`.

Assuming `gasten` is UTF-8:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gasten_url_toegangscodes` (
  /* use same charset for this column */
  `uniek` varchar(64) NOT NULL CHARSET UTF-8,
  `unieke_url_code` char(64) NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(16) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (uniek) REFERENCES `gasten` (`uniek`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```